# Would mermaid be able to leap higher out of water with a Fosbury flop?

Tags: biology, merfolk, sports, mermaid

In a high jump sport on land, athletes would adopt Fosbury flop technique to cross over a bar. This bar is the indicator of how high an individual can jump with reference to the ground, so I wonder could a mermaid adopt this technique to leap over the "dragon gate", the legendary height barrier for a merfolk which is exactly 4x it's body length? Current world record is 3.87x body length by a merfolk named Rosbury. I believed that it is much trickier for a mermaid because they have to turn their body more to avoid their dorsal fin from ruining the record.

Comment: Are mermaids permitted tail accessories/equipment like how humans are permitted sneakers that have been proven to affect a human's ability to jump? If so I'd recommend something like a fin extender(more powerful swim thrust) and a suit that, if worn, ends up making them more aquadynamic than what is naturally provided by their bodies.

Comment: Whales jump backwards out of water at times with some being side on at their peak height so this style of jumping for height makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For humans, equipped with two legs, the Fosbury technique is advantageous because it allows to push the center of mass high up by raising the knee of the non pushing leg during the jump, and then rotating around it by recalling the pushing leg while directing the head/upper torso down: during the high jump the CoM actually doesn't go above the barrier, thanks to the arc of the body.

[image]

Also the once in fashion barrel roll technique use the elevation of the passive leg to raise the CoM, though it then moves the CoM above the barrier

[image]

For a mermaid, equipped with a single tail, that's going to prove more difficult or impossible: the tail must be in the water until the very last moment to ensure propulsion, and there will be less help in raising the CoM by just raising the arms.

Also, the need to provide also the horizontal thrust with the tail limits the amount of energy directed against the gravity, while in the Fosbury one can use the last moment rotation to move horizontally past the barrier.

Comment: I wonder if it can be compared that easily with a jump on land. The pose of the arms will be different.  Merfolk will probably have to stretch their arms forward, when coming out of the water, like a diving move, to maximize speed. But would merfolk need to turn 180 degrees ? the arms are already up.. Having a way to swing your arms upward and keep them away from the bar easily while jumping over it is an advantage in athletics, it's easier to use the flop jump, because the arms are hanging down when the jump sets in.

Comment: What if she has really thick arms?  I mean seriously burly.  Not all muscle either.  And long fingers.

Comment: I love the detail about high jumping, but there is something else here to consider: arms. Keeping arms up (this higher CoM) assumes a larger benefit than pushing down on the water as you come out. I imagine this is a debate among mermaid high-jumpers.

Comment: I'm not sure that two-leggedness is so important, since a mermaid can get a vertical "running start", unlike a human who needs to turn their forward momentum into vertical momentum in just a fraction of a second during the jump takeoff. A mermaid wouldn't need to swing their arms or legs to make their center of mass move upward, since they're already swimming upward toward the surface in the run-up to the jump.

Answer (score 3):

**Fosbury Bellyflop.**

[image]

Mermaids jump over the bar making a C shape of their body, and rotating as they pass over the bar so their hands and tail remain below the bar and their belly passes over it. Mermaids like [dolphins have no trouble rotating midair.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52dtE2kQzpY)

In fact Mermaids are better at flopping than humans. The reason Humans flop on their back is because knees bend backwards and not forwards.

It is easier for a human to make the C shape with the hands and knees below the bar (see the images provided by L.Dutch) and the back facing the bar. This puts the mass of the legs and arms below the centre of gravity when facing upwards. If our knees bent the other way we would flop facing downwards.

Since mermaid tails bend upwards as easily as downwards, they prefer to flop on their bellies. (Arms are flexible enough to work either way.) This avoids the dorsal fin hitting the bar.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Right you are!